# VB.NET 4.5 Moving controls on an excel sheet at runtime

Tags: excel, controls, move, ribbon

I am using Visual Basic 2013 with VSTO in Visual Studio 2013 on a 64 bit windows 8.1 professional platform.
I have created a ribbon addin that allows the user to place controls on a spreadsheet via that ribbon. I have been trying to add additional functionality so that when the user clicks/drags a control (a Windows.Forms.Button in this case) it can be dragged (or just moved) to another point on the sheet.
I simply can’t find a way to do this. I can get it to move but only inside its display rectangle (I think) so that the button partly (or totally depending on how far I move it) disappears. I can’t really post any meaningful code as I have tried/retried, written/rewritten it numerous times without much success.
Do you know how or if I can move these controls/buttons within a sheet?
Thanks,

Added some additional info below:

I’ve cleaned up some code which might assist you if you are looking at this issue. The first part below are event handlers for the mousedown and mousemove events. These allow the control button to be moved but you see it as if through a window in the spreadsheet (the display rectangle?) and the button will disappear if you move it beyond the bounds of the viewing rectangle while holding the mouse button down.

```
Private Sub button1_mousedown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    Dim sentButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Dim a, b As Rectangle

    a = sentButton.ClientRectangle
    b = sentButton.DisplayRectangle

    xy = Control.MousePosition.X - sentButton.Location.X
    yx = Control.MousePosition.Y - sentButton.Location.Y
End Sub

Private Sub button1_mousemove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    Dim sentButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        newpoint = Control.MousePosition
        newpoint.X -= xy
        newpoint.Y -= yx
        sentButton.Location = newpoint

        Application.DoEvents()
    End If
End Sub
```

These event handlers are called from the parent form with the following style of allocation:

```
AddHandler button.MouseDown, AddressOf button1_mousedown ' handles mouse down
```

One other puzzling thing. If I resize the control it works ok. That is, it does not disappear any part of the control even if it is now bigger than it was previously though I have not explicitly done anything to allow for the increased or decreased size. I can resize with a line such as the below:

```
sentButton.SetBounds(20, 20, 100, 50)
```

Question again: Do you know how or if I can move these controls/buttons within a sheet?